# html() method in Quill formula.js

Tags: mathjax, quill

In the Quill editor, I try to adapt the formula module for using it with MathJax.

I do not understand what is the `html()` method used in the `Formula` class : https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/develop/formats/formula.js

Moreover, it seems never being called. Is anyone has an idea of what this method is for?

Comment: Which version of quill are you using? Looks like html() is only available in the beta versions (if you look at the [commit history](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/commits/develop/formats/formula.js) you can see that the latest is adding the support of the html method)

Comment: I'm using version 1.3.6. If you look at the formula.js module : https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/develop/formats/formula.js the html() method is in the current source code (line 23)

Comment: You are linking to the develop branch: this is the latest code. 
If you look at the [1.3.6 tag](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/releases/tag/v1.3.6) you will see that the corresponding commit is 96e38e9. Now if you look at the files from this commit, [you will see that the formula](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/96e38e92637b75b907579d0cc1b201920aebe38c/modules/formula.js) (which is actually in modules and not format, in this version) does not contain the html method.